# How to find a sub-forcing?

Tags: lo.logic, forcing, set-theory

Suppose that $M$ is a model of ZFC, $P\in M$ is a notion of forcing and $G$ is a $P$-generic filter over $M$.

It is a well-known theorem that if $M\subseteq N\subseteq M[G]$, and $N$ is a model of ZFC then $N=M[H]$ for some generic set $H$, and there is some $H'$ which is generic over $M[H]$ such that $M[G]=M[H][H']$.

But the proof I know uses Boolean valued models and is not particularly insightful about the following question:

> Suppose that $M$ is a model of ZFC, $P\in M$ is a notion of forcing, and $\dot x$ is a $P$-name, such that if $G$ is a $P$-generic over $M$, and $x=\dot x^G$ then $G\notin M[x]$.
>
> Can we give an explicit $Q\in M$ such that $x$ is $Q$-generic over $M$?

An additional question which is relevant to one particular case:

> Suppose that $P$ is the Cohen forcing with $2^{<\omega}$. In such case every sub-forcing is isomorphic to $P$, what does that mean for us? Does it mean that the generic needs to be particularly chosen, or what?

Comment: I feel that "sub-forcing" is the wrong term, but I can't recall any better term at the moment. Any suggestions on terminology (or approvals) would be welcomed.

Comment: Sub-forcing is fine, but I take this to mean simply the forcing extension obtained by a complete sub-algebra of the complete Boolean algebra giving rise to the extension, and this is the same thing as an intermediate ZFC model $M\subset N\subset M[G]$. I don't understand your second question---could you clarify what you want?

Comment: Joel, it's simple. Suppose $P$ was the product of two random reals, which adds a Cohen. We can consider the sub-forcing which only adds this Cohen. Clearly this subforcing is very simple and the full forcing is... less simple. But if we start with a Cohen forcing then the subforcing is again a Cohen forcing, for obvious reasons. So now how do we discern between the two results? Those would have to be two different generics, in some sense, but surely there is some way to say that $G$ is "more generic" than $x$.

Comment: I see. In general, since adding a Cohen real is countably-dense forcing, it is not difficult to see that every sub-forcing of it is also countably-dense and hence the same as Cohen real forcing. Furthermore, the quotient forcing is also countably-dense, and hence also Cohen-real forcing. So every factorization of Cohen real forcing is just adding two Cohen reals. 

Comment: Exactly. This is why I wanted to try and understand how we can better discern between those two Cohens, the first is just a regular Cohen at your local temple, but the other is the great Cohen at the temple in Jerusalem. (And this is as far I will go with this analogy for tonight! :-))

Comment: I don't think you can "better discern between those two Cohens." Suppose $M$ is a countable transitive model of ZFC and $c$ is *any* Cohen real over it. Then $c$ can play the role of the great Cohen; just split it into its odd and even halves and note that adding these separately amounts to adding $c$.  But $c$ can also play the role of a "regular Cohen at your local temple"; just take some real $c'$ Cohen-generic over $M[c]$ and let the interleaving of $c$ and $c'$ serve as the great Cohen. So nothing about an individual Cohen can tell you whether it's great or regular.

Comment: Andreas, thanks. I suspected as much. I have other questions, but each and every one of them is of this spirit and they all seem to amount to something like "Either you know what is the great Cohen, or you can't really say anything intelligible".

Answer (score 4):

The intermediate model proof for $M\subset N\subset M[G]$ is not
so inexplicit. The situation is that, if $A\subset\text{Ord}$ is a
set of ordinals coding $P(\mathbb{B})^N$, the $N=M[G\cap
\mathbb{B}_0]$, where $\mathbb{B}_0$ is the Boolean algebra
generated by the $\mathbb{B}$-Boolean values of membership in
$\dot A$, where $\dot A$ is a $\mathbb{B}$-name for $A$. (This is
proved in Jech.) After all, if you know $G$ on this
$\mathbb{B}_0$, then you know $P(\mathbb{B})^N$ and hence all of
$N$ (as in Jech), and conversely, $N$ certainly knows the right
answers for $\dot A$.

In your case, you have $N=M[x]$, and so $A$ is any set of ordinals coding $P(\mathbb{B})^{M[x]}$ in $M[x]$, with $\mathbb{B}_0$ the Boolean values generated by the values $\[\check\alpha\in\dot A\]^{\mathbb{B}}$.

Meanwhile, one cannot get *too* explicit about it, since the proof
in Jech uses AC and the fact is not generally true for ZF as
opposed to ZFC models. First of all, note that there can be intermediate ZF models. For example, one might start with $M=L$, say, and add $\omega_1$ many Cohen reals, to form $M[G]$. Let $N=L(\mathbb{R})^{M[G]}$, which is intermediate between $M$ and $M[G]$, but it doesn't have the form $M[G\cap\mathbb{B}_0]$ for any complete subalgebra, since it violates AC. In general, no intermediate $\text{ZF}+\neg\text{AC}$ model can be $M[G\cap\mathbb{B}_0]$, since these satisfy ZFC.

Comment: Oh, about that counterexample, I am actually working towards reconstructing, generalizing, and further development of such counterexample. :-)

Comment: I should also say that I don't mind having this poset definable from the name itself (either by a general choicey algorithm, or explicitly if the name is nice enough. At the moment, however, I don't know what is the name, so I can't really say more...)

Comment: I was just looking at such a counterexample recently, but I don't recall now...

Comment: Joel, when you write "Boolean values of membership in $\dot A$", Do you mean the subalgebra whose $1$ element is $\sum[\dot a\in\dot A]$ over all the elements which $1\not\Vdash\dot a\notin\dot A$ or something like that?

Comment: I mean the complete Boolean subalgebra of $\mathbb{B}$ generated by the elements of the form $\[\check\alpha\in\dot A\]$. The one element of the subalgebra will be the same as the one element of $\mathbb{B}$. 

Comment: Basically, this subalgebra knows all about the possible elements of $\dot A$, and nothing else. One direction of the inclusion is that $N$ knows the true membership relation for $\alpha\in A$. 

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. I'll sleep it over and resume tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Joel. Shouldn't a true $\lnot\mathsf{AC}$ counterexample be $M\subset N\subset M[G]$ with $N$ not a symmetric extension of $M$?

Comment: That would be nice. Do you know any? I think I remember seeing one built by doing symmetric stuff higher and higher up, instead of at the same level as the forcing itself. This would seem to be a better class of counterexample, but still symmetric.

Comment: In fact, I think I recall seeing that there was a proper class of intermediate models, depending on how high one went. This would certainly refute the idea that they were all just obtained via subalgebras in some regular way.

Comment: Andres, Joel: Magidor told me about some model they worked on in a workshop in Bristol two years ago which is a counterexample. Sadly, no one wrote the details of the construction. I got a few hints from Magidor, but he couldn't completely restore this construction. I felt that this might be a good start for the project I have picked for my Ph.D. work, so I am going to start with this. But other than this model (whom I aptly named "The Hidden Bristol Model") I don't know many examples.

Comment: Joel, is $N$ in your counterexample not simply taking permutations on $\omega_1$ and applying them in the obvious way on the forcing, and considering the symmetric extension generated by the filter of subgroups fixing finitely (or maybe countably?) many points?